# How to I delimit a string and store each part in different vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector, getline

I have a text file that has many lines, an example is

john:student:business

may:lecturer:math

bob:student:math

how do i split them up and store them in different vectors such as:

vector1: john, may, bob

vector2: student, lecturer, student

vector3: business, math, math

my current code is:

```
ifstream readDetails(argv[1]);
while (getline (readEvents, line, ':')){
    cout << line << endl;
}
```

it only splits the string up, but i could not think of any ways to separate the string and store them into vectors.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of vectors and play with the token index.

If the stream can sometimes have less tokens, you will need to handle that case.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
int main() {

    const int NUM_TOKENS = 3;
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> v(NUM_TOKENS);
    int token = 0;
    std::string str("Mary:Had:Lamb");
    std::istringstream split(str);
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline (split, line, ':')){
        v[token++].push_back(line);
        if ( token == NUM_TOKENS )
            token = 0;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a nested vector (aka 2D vector) and nested loops. The outer loop is for splitting the input into lines, the inner loop for splitting the tokens of each line which are separated by `':'`.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::istringstream in{
        "john:student:business\n"
        "may:lecturer:math\n"
        "bob:student:math"
    };

    std::vector< std::vector< std::string > > v{ 3 }; // Number of tokens per line

    std::string line;
    // Loop over the lines
    while( std::getline( in, line ) ) {
        std::istringstream lineStrm{ line };
        // Loop to split the tokens of the current line
        for( auto& col : v ) {
            std::string token;
            std::getline( lineStrm, token, ':' );
            col.push_back( token );
        }
    } 
}
```

[Live demo on Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6c4185fc3066d8c)

Answer (score 0):

Create vectors of strings and store your data accordingly. Without using `std::istringstream`, you can basically take advantage of `substr()` and `find()` that come with String class, hence:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    ifstream inFile("data.txt");
    string line;
    vector<string> vStr1,vStr2, vStr3;

    while( std::getline( inFile, line ) ){
        string::size_type idx1 = line.find(":");
        string::size_type idx2 = line.rfind(":");
        vStr1.push_back(line.substr(0,idx1));
        vStr2.push_back(line.substr(idx1+1,idx2-idx1-1));
        vStr3.push_back(line.substr(idx2+1));   
    }

    cout << "vector1: ";
    for(int i(0); i < vStr1.size(); ++i ){
        cout << vStr1[i] << " "; 
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "vector2: ";
    for(int i(0); i < vStr2.size(); ++i ){
        cout << vStr2[i] << " "; 
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "vector3: ";
    for(int i(0); i < vStr3.size(); ++i ){
        cout << vStr3[i] << " "; 
    }
    cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
vector1: john may bob
vector2: student lecturer student
vector3: business math math
```